# Show that the directional derivative is linear by definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, the map $h\mapsto f(x+h)-f(x)$ should be approximately linear. The scalar multiplicativity can be seen by noting that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+ch)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}c\frac{f(x+ch)-f(x)}{ch}= c\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\quad \text{and}\\ \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+ctv)-f(x)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}c\frac{f(x+ctv)-f(x)}{ct}=c\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t},$$

where on the second line, $x$ and $v$ are vectors. The additivity of this map is less easy to see for me. How can we show it? That is, how to show that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+t(v+w))-f(x)}{t} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+tw)-f(x)}{t}?$$

Comment: Are you assuming differentiability?  If so, you need only show that $Df(v)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$, which is not too hard.  If you are not assuming differentiability, I do not think you can get anywhere.  In particular, a function can be Gâteaux differentiable with its Gâteaux derivative nonlinear.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative

Comment: Could you help me understand what you're doing? In the title you ask about showing that the directional derivative is linear but then in the question you don't actually use the [expression for the directional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Definition) (which would include the direction vector).

Comment: @MattN. $h$ is the direction vector in the first part, $v$ in the second part. It's confusing because in the article you link to, $h$ is a scalar. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The subtlety here, Eric, is that when you're working with a function $f\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, the *definition* of differentiability is far stronger than the assumption of existence of all directional derivatives. So you must use linearity as part of the definition; you cannot derive it (pun intended). (In particular, consider $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\,, & (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0\,, & (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}.$$ This function has all directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ but is *not* differentiable at $(0,0)$.) You *need* linearity of the derivative to prove directional derivatives are linear.

A good question to pose is this: *Suppose* you have linearity in the directional derivatives. Is this sufficient to guarantee differentiability? (**Hint**: There are functions discontinuous at $(0,0)$ with all directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ equal to $0$ !!)

Comment: I'm sorry but could you help me understand this? What I understand so far: In higher dimension [the definition of the derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) involves a matrix so it is linear. On the other hand, the [directional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) does not seem to include such a matrix. Why does it nonetheless follow from the definition of directional derivative that it is linear? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @MattN: If you compute the directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ of the function in my answer, you will most definitely see that they are *not* linear in the direction.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't understand. I think I'm confused by the question. I'll post a comment there...